# Openlayers draw interaction: Error: drag and drop of map after click

Tags: javascript, openlayers, draw

I am trying to add a draw interaction to my map. The user should click a button, add one point and then add attribute information about the point. I'm still stuck in the drawing part: After I draw a point in the map, the cursor position remains the same and mouse movements change the map in the background (like when panning). When I click again this stops. No idea why it's doing this. In the console in Chrome I get an error in the draw.js file from openlayers (this.source_.addFeature is not a function).

Grateful for any help!

Here's my code:

```
    function addFeature() {
                var btn_cancel = document.getElementById('buttonCancel');
                btn_cancel.style.display = 'block';
    
                var btn_add = document.getElementById('buttonAdd');
                btn_add.classList.add("button_clicked");
    
                var draw; 
                function addInteraction() {
                    draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
                        source: lunchvec,
                        type: "Point",
                    });
                    map.addInteraction(draw);

                    draw.on('drawend', function(evt) {
                        console.log(evt.feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates());
                        map.removeInteraction(draw);
                    });
    
                };
    
                addInteraction();
}
```